# Solr Upgrade from 3.4 to 4

Tags: solr

In order to make use of pivot feature present on Solr 4, I upgraded from 3.4.

Shall I proceed with a full reindex of the content due this upgrade or are they compatible somehow?

And regarding my client-applications that are currently accessing my solr server 3.4, will they present problem after upgrade? (The preliminary test I did they are running, seems the xml schema returned in a query response didn't changed when you don't use new features)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a full reindex if you want to use the Solr 4 index structure. Else you need to change the Lucene version in solrconfig to use the old index.

The schema will need a new field called `_version_` if you want to use the [Real Time Get](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/RealTimeGet) functionality.

Other then that most things are pretty much the same for the client.

Comment: Did you mean the lucene match version? That doesn't have that much to do with the index version...only with old lucene behaviours. If I'm not wrong lucene 4 can only read the old index, but the index will be upgraded under the hood as soon as you write on it. Afer that you can't read the same index with an 3.x version anymore. Do you agree? Of course it's not like a reindex, you might want to reindex anyway if you need the _version field on all documents for example.